# How to process directory first, then files and directories under it?

Tags: find

On my Linux system, I've got into a situation where there are not write/execute permissions on directories on a mounted drive. As a result, I can't get into a directory before I open its permissions up. This happens every time I mount that drive. The mounting operation is done by a tool under its hood, so I doubt if could modify mount parameters to address this problem.

As a workaround, I am using this `find` command to modify permissions on directories. I use it repetitively, since it gets one more level of directories on each run.

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 chmod a+wrx
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this. I wonder if there is a `find` option that processes a directory first and then its contents - the opposite of `-depth|-d` option.

Any tips?

Comment: Initially posted at http://stackoverflow.com/q/12040396/305686

Comment: For future reference, it is usually best to ask a moderator to migrate a question you want moved instead of posting a duplicate-copy.  It keeps the various sites better organized and helps people find answers more easily that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod a+rwx {} ';'
```

This will cause `find` to execute the `chmod` before it tries to read the directory rather than trying to generate a list and feed it to `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Next time I'll put a little more thought on use of `-exec` versus `xargs`.